# optimization tips recommended for this query

Tags: oracle, optimization

I have these queries

```
select decode(sum(txn_amount),'',0,sum(txn_amount)) as txn_amount, count(txn_id) as txn_num,
currency_code, (select rpt_descr from rptcodesmtb 
where rpt_code = txnmtb.txn_type and rpt_type='txn_type' 
and merchant_id = txnmtb.merchant_id) AS txn_type from txnmtb 
where txn_date between TO_DATE('2010-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE('2019-09-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
and merchant_id = 2 and txn_type IN  
('FTO','DOMACH','BUYCOUPON','INTBOOKTRF','SIDOMRTGS','RTGS','BP_SCHEDR','DOMRTGS','DOMESTICRTGS','BP','FT_SCHEDR','MC','DOMESTICACH','INTERNAL','DOMBOOK','NETBANK','PP_SCHEDR','PREPAID','ACH','DOMESTIC','SIDOMBOOKTR','SIBILLPAY','SENDGIFT','FTA','FTB','SIDOMACH','MC_SCHEDULER','SIDOMESTIC','DOMESTICBOOKTRF','REDEEMGIFT','FTL','MCC_SCHEDR')       
group by merchant_id, txn_type,currency_code
```

I'm getting a total costs of 6062, the major costs is due to the date range selection. even after adding index for the where condition like create index txnmtb_idx on txnmtb(TO_DATE(txn_date),merchant_id,txn_type) i did not notice any decrease on cost, also if the function is changed from to_date to to_timestamp i'm getting lesser costs even if the column datatype for txn_date is DATE. The oracle DB seems to always do a full table scan regardless of index is present or not.

Also i would like to know if left JOIN is possible to remove this query select rpt_descr from rptcodesmtb where rpt_code=txnmtb.txn_type and rpt_type='txn_type' and merchant_id= txnmtb.merchant_id, the cost for this query is mentioned as 1

Explain plan is

[image: Index plan]

Comment: Try an index on `(merchant_id, txn_type, txn_date)`

Comment: Already tried that also, No change in cost. We are expecting 3 lakh rows to be present in the table

Comment: You said you tried an index on `(TO_DATE(txn_date),merchant_id,txn_type)`. I suggested a different one. Also, the costs and plans may be different but how efficent is the query with the different indexes? How much time does ot need to run, have you done tests?

Comment: 300K rows is a rather small table. How many rows pass the WHERE conditions?

Comment: That `TO_DATE()` in the index is worthless if `txn_date` is already a DATE.  That index wont be used if the query doesn't match the Function Based Index (and it doesnt).  Also, look at (and post) the plan; you may need to move that scalar query to a cte/subquery

Comment: We are expecting 3 lakh rows means for a given date range a maximum of 3 lakh rows will be selected, the maximum number of rows can reach more than 10 lakhs above that we are archiving it to a separate table. I even tried changing the query with left joins for rptcodesmtb  table but the cost only increased instead of decreasing

Comment: Expecting 3 lakh rows within date range but plan shows 750 rows?What is total number of rows in that table.

Comment: total records is 3 lakhs , since this returns a count it's returning few, the above query is one type . there are also other queries which will return 3 lakh rows.

Comment: Focusing on the cost of an execution plan isn't worth it. Better is to focus on the performance of the query; some queries with a high cost can run quickly, others with a low cost can run slower than you'd think. As for whether you need to move the scalar subquery into a left outer join - I'd say not, since you're grouping on machine_id amongst other things (reducing the number of rows per machine_id). Also, you can have the benefits of scalar subquery caching, meaning that several rows with the same machine_id will only run the subquery once, and then use the cached result for the others..

Comment: so if there are no group by's is left join worth it because i have an another query which doesn't have a group by but has a subselect query like above but the cost with left join is almost the double . how do i measure the performance of a query